# How to translate content from select in ember with ember-i18n addon?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-i18n

I´ve the follwing code from the ember.select example http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

```
var yehuda = {firstName: "Yehuda", id: 1, bff4eva: 'tom'}
var tom = {title: "totranslate", id: 2, bff4eva: 'yehuda'};

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedPerson: tom,
  programmers: [
    yehuda,
    tom
  ]
});
```

How would i translate the title "totranslate"?

Ember-i18n addon (https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n)  is setup and working.

Comment: are you translating data?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe sorry, i don´t know what you mean

Comment: Are you trying to translate the data that you're binding to your select?

Comment: I don't think this plugin was built with *data* translation in mind, and honestly, I don't know that the persistent data should be translated at all. If you have a use case in which your *data* needs to be translated, do this on the server and just have your app receive the translated data.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe thanks, i will use the server for this case. Do you know how to to it, if the answer to your question was no?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Did check how [other people do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IICD0vAQ3h8)?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe thanks for the link, but i know how to to things like that, but not with a select.

Comment: I don't see the use case of translating persistent data, especially in the sample code you provided. Are you trying to achieve anything specific or you're just trying i18n out?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe  simple case: in a select you can choose between yes and no. How would you do it, if you need yes and no in multiple languages?

Comment: You'll have to write it all, unless your backend has trasnlation support already implemented. I use .NET which has resx files for this. I think rails uses yml. Before your user even sees anything on your site, your server should know which language it has to deliver stuff in, and internally it would have translate the data text to a given language, picking up the correspinding value from a translation file, much like the i18n plugin. Once in your client app, the server should already know what to do in regards to these translations as they are not persistent data, but rather just labels.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe thank you for your time. Not the answer i was hoping for, but now i know where to start from